# Using classified variables in Parallel for loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor, matlabpool

Hi I am trying to run a code for image reconstruction of 2D projections using the iradon transform. My aim to reduce the time significantly for which I am trying to using parallel for loop in my local cluster profile of my laptop.
But I seem to get an error which I am finding it difficult to debug-

Error: The variable data in a parfor cannot be classified.

My code-

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

tic
% projection_length = input('Define projection length (px) = ');
projection_length = 4100;  % which means our ouput will have 4100 cross sectional images of the capillary tube

parfor q = 1:projection_length

  for i = 1:5  % typically 500, since we take 500 projections around the capillary tube 0.72 deg inc
      if length(num2str(i)) == 1
           data(q,:, i) = imread(['pre00' num2str(i) '.tif'], 'PixelRegion', {[1 1600], [q q]});
      elseif length(num2str(i)) == 2
           data(q,:, i) = imread(['pre0' num2str(i) '.tif'], 'PixelRegion', {[1 1600], [q q]});
      elseif length(num2str(i)) == 3
           data(q,:, i) = imread(['pre' num2str(i) '.tif'], 'PixelRegion', {[1 1600], [q q]});
      end

      disp(['Analyzing projection ' num2str(q)  ' of ' num2str(projection_length) ', Angle ' num2str(i) '...']);
  end
  H = iradon( data(q,:,:), 0.72, 'Hann', 0.8, 1600);
end
toc
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would recommend using `sprintf` to build the filename, like so:

```
fname = sprintf('pre%03d.tif', i);
data(q, :, i) = imread(fname, ...);
```

This will correctly zero-pad `fname`.

The problem with `data` is that you're indexing it in different ways, and unfortunately `parfor` cannot understand that correctly. (This should show up as a "red" warning in the MATLAB editor, which can sometimes give you better information about `parfor` problems). I would be tempted to fix the problem something like this:

```
parfor q = 1:projection_length
    tmpData = zeros(N, numFiles); % insert correct value of N here
    for i = 1:numFiles
        fname = ...;
        tmpData(:, i) = imread(fname, ...);
    end
    data(q, :, :) = tmpData;
    H = iradon(tmpData, ...);
end
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `H` - `parfor` will treat that as a temporary variable, and the value will not be available after the loop.

Comment: My aim is to make this more efficient i.e the time that it takes to run reduces significantly. Is there is anything else that can be done to reduce the time taken like a memory allocation. Can tempdata be predefined before the parforloop? Will it reduce the time? Or are there any other suggestions for the same?

Comment: Hey and the code after the iradon is here as follows, I have to save each reconstructed image.                                                                     H = iradon(tmpData, 0.72, 'Hann', 0.8, 1600 ); 
   postfname= sprintf('pos%06d.tif', q);
   imwrite(H, postfname);                                                                       But I keep getting an error message-Error using parallel_function (line 589)

Couldn't open 'pos001328.tif' for writing.

Error stack:
writetif.m at 107
imwrite.m at 477

Error in Parallel_Reconstruction (line 8)
parfor q = 1:projection_length

Comment: It runs a few iterations and pops up this error! Any suggestions to debug this?